# How to setup a dynamic web application for multiple developers using github,eclipse,maven?

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven, tomcat

We are trying to build a web application and our sources are managed through [github](https://github.com/tamimcsedu19/amaderbari).

But, We are using maven,tomcat,eclipse,spring mvc,jsp etc. But the problem is setting up the project for each one of us. When I create a server for tomcat in eclipse,I have to give an absolute path of my PC(ubuntu). But when other create server(on windows) they have to give their absolute path.

So my question is , should I have to upload the whole tomcat server , maven .m2 repository , etc to the github ? Or there is some other way to manage this ?

Comment: Use Spring Boot and an embedded container. No external server configuration or installation to manage.

Comment: Server info must be in an external configuration file that has not to be commited to control version system. Each one of you must have his configuration file. .m2 repo shouldn't be commited neither.

Comment: Where exactly do you use an absolute path?

Comment: /home/user/java/tomcat

Comment: Where do you have to set an absolute path?

Comment: While creating a server in eclipse for tomcat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of ways of get what you're asking for.

The server is always a problem, because it's not part of the application itself (it's part of the infrastructure needed), and it's a platform dependent component.

So my suggestion is: If you can use Spring boot, your developers can run the application inside the tomcat embedded (starting it java -jar yourapp.jar) and you can deploy it as standalone or generating a war.

I'm currently using this approach:

Spring boot application with two profiles: dev (with development configuration) and prod (with all the production configuration)

Using this, no matters what SO/platform is running each teammate, everyone can download the application and start it without any local configuration.

Take a look at Jhipster, a very good starting point using Spring Boot:

https://jhipster.github.io

Answer (score 0):

1. Goto http://start.spring.io/
2. Create a spring project with embeded tomcat or jetty.
3. Run the application with the gradle wrapper (gradlew bootRun) so you don't even have to install gradle.
4. Modify the application as per use case.
5. Initialize a git repository.
6. Commit and push it to a github or bit bucket

Tell others to clone the repository and follow from step 4

Comment: The question says he's using maven, not gradle

Comment: Can you please tell me the What options will I have to choose if I want to create a project just like that of 'Spring MVC using STS plugin of eclipse' ?

Comment: you can just import it as gradle or maven project in sts.